# Bulk Add Items on mobile device

Tags: forms, lists, inline-edit

I want to allow users to add multiple entries to a list of rather complex items. The user needs to pick

- color
- number
- date
- dropdown
- dropdown
- (later a optional picture)

putting this in a single page form on a mobile device is quite straightforward, but users will eventually add multiple items quickly. Going back and forth between the list and the form seems suboptimal, but I am unsure how to layout a batch add.

Comment: Can you provide bit more context; what is in the dropdowns, what does it means complex items, how many items per UI is there, do you use table / card style, do the items have some information same....

Comment: Do you have any screen shots you can provide?

Comment: @xul I wanted to go for cards. I replaced the dropdowns with choice Chips
so there are 4 categories of each 6 items. With the date and the descriptive text, it already takes up more than half of the screen space. I guess it doesn't make sense to go for cards. I think I will go with Mokshs idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to introduce a default value or recently used value already filled in the new form or some kind of checkbox for new form to auto populate the values from previous entry (mark it checked by default)

This might speed up the adding entry process.

Also, you can always have "Save and Add New" button to skip going to list view and adding the items quickly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I'll try this